# Client side predicition tick implementation

Tags: networking, client-server

I've been reading about client side prediction and one question I have is what's the best way to implement the server tick. I thought about using the server frame count from the game engine I'm using as an authorative tick, is this advisable due to the changes with delta time or should I just use a simple timer on the server?